# How to add image in EXTJS textfield for empty text

Tags: extjs

Team.

Does anyone know how to add image inside extjs textfield

Basically I have text field where I am showing empty text by default and besides that I want to put one image ( Image should be inside text field.) is there any way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean an image that indicates that this is a required field?

Answer (score 8):

Ext 4.1

Your field:

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Field with image',
        emptyText: 'placeholder text', // important, or image will not show
        name: 'name',
        emptyCls: 'empty-text-field'
    }
```

Your css:

```
.empty-text-field {
    background-image:url(/images/cross.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

If you want show images in all empty text fields, you only have to add this css:

```
.x-form-empty-field {
    background-image:url(/images/cross.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

(`x-form-empty-field` is the default emtptyCls for a form field)

don't forget the emptyText

[screenshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/6795/20130125-s3as-8kb.jpg)

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, OP just has to be aware that you won't get the squiggly line anymore.

Comment: @JuanMendes You about allowBlank line? Shee show, if field has focus: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/6795/20130125-fesc-10kb.jpg

Comment: What I mean is exactly that, the image doesn't display when the squiggly is there, because your CSS is not specific enough. If it was specific enough, it would override the squiggly line